# Warning on advertise of std_mgs/Empty

Tags: ros, std-msgs, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently (maybe since some update...), whenever I advertise a topic of topic std_msgs/Empty I receive WARNING:

> Advertising on topic [/topic_name]
> with an empty message definition. Some
> tools (e.g. rosbag) may not work
> correctly.

Can I safely ignore it? Was does it mean? I often use std_msgs/Empty as kind of signal for nodes to perform long running calculations to update their state.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121971/warning-on-advertise-of-std_mgs/empty/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-01-24**:
I have also just run into this problem, a recent update seems to have changed functionality.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-01-24**:
I just opened an issue https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bug responsible for this warning has been fixed in `gencpp`. Please update your packages - ros-hydro-gencpp needs to be version 0.4.16 (or newer).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1